# Ubuntu 14.04 not able to login to system using password.

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am working in ubuntu 14.04' but today when I start my desktop it is not taking my password.not able to login using guest as well. But when I give cntrl alt f2 I am able to login with credentials. I am giving correct password. Can anybody help me to login to my desktop

Answer (score 0):

*Are you seeing an error message stating Log-in incorrect even after system restarts? If 'Yes' its a possible corruption for /etc/password (again this is one of the possibility)*

**Solution - Boot into single user mode, back up /etc/passwad- to /etc/passwd.**

```
Steps for the above process

    1. Restart the machine and in the very inital state press any key to enter into the GRUB menu. Select your os from the list.
    2. Select kernel, press e to edit parameteres. Add 1 after a space to boot in single user mode
    3. Now copy the backup of /etc/passwd which is /etc/passwd-.  'cp /etc/passwd- /etc/passwd'
    4. enter commant 'init 5' to enter graphical mode
```

Comment: i am not seeing any error messages. After entering password and i hit enter it tries to login and again same login screen appears no error messages. same is happenning for Guest user also. Only when i try to hit wrong password it says login incorrect.

Comment: I dont want to re install ubuntu as i have not taken backup. Can you please let me know is there an option to recover data in above scenario.

Comment: @Haraharamahadev - not the best solution but you can try to reset password in single user mode. Also try to address /etc/passwd file if you feel worth the trial.

Comment: well you get in single user mode and reset password for your user. follow the instructions above for getting in single user mode

Comment: i am able to change my password, when i press cntrl + alt + f2 at my login screen it takes me to terminal i am able to change password there, Still i am not able to login with the changed password.i have 1 user and 1 guest user, for guest user ther is no password and for user there is a password. Not able to login to both the sessions. Kindly help

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue after i changed the entry in sudo nano /etc/environment, which i had made previously. After clearing the entry whihc addedd as part of previous change. Issue got resolved and able to login

Comment: curious - I usually hear to stay away from system wide environment file. Any specific use case to modify /etc/environment?